# Easy Leetcode: BST depth first search has stack overflow bug

Tags: python, recursion, binary-search-tree, depth-first-search

I'm working on a Leetcode problem, that can be found here: https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-distance-between-bst-nodes/

**Problem**:
Given a Binary Search Tree (BST) with the root node root, return the minimum difference between the values of any two different nodes in the tree.

Example :

Input: root = [4,2,6,1,3,null,null]
Output: 1
Explanation:
Note that root is a TreeNode object, not an array.

The given tree [4,2,6,1,3,null,null] is represented by the following diagram:

```
      4
    /   \
  2      6
 / \    
1   3
```

while the minimum difference in this tree is 1, it occurs between node 1 and node 2, also between node 3 and node 2.

**Note**: I have implemented preorder traversal but my code ran into stack overflow bug, could someone help point out where the logic error is?

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode(object):
#     def __init__(self, x):
#         self.val = x
#         self.left = None
#         self.right = None

class Solution(object):
    def minDiffInBST(self, root):
        min_value = float('inf')

        def helper(node, min_value):
            print(node.val, "and", min_value)
            # if root is None
            if not root: 
                return None

            if node.left:
                min_value = min(min_value, node.val - node.left.val)
            if node.right:
                min_value = min(min_value, node.right.val - node.val)

            helper(root.left, min_value)
            helper(root.right, min_value)

            return min_value

        helper(root, min_value)
```

AFTER CHANGES:

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode(object):
#     def __init__(self, x):
#         self.val = x
#         self.left = None
#         self.right = None

class Solution(object):
    def minDiffInBST(self, root):
        min_value = float('inf')

        def helper(node, min_value):
            # if root is None
            if not node: 
                return node
            print(node.val, min_value)

            if (node.left):
                min_value = min(min_value, node.val - node.left.val)
            if (node.right):
                min_value = min(min_value, node.right.val - node.val)

            helper(node.left, min_value)
            helper(node.right, min_value)

            return min_value

        helper(root, min_value)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `helper` function you use `root` in the recursive call instead the current `node`. So instead iterating the whole tree, you continuously are calling the `helper` method for the same node, which is why the program gets stuck in an infinite recursion.
It is very helpful to use a debugger for stepping through the code to investigate such issues.

Comment: Couldn’t believe I made such a silly mistake. Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you for helping, but could you please help look at my updated code. It stops running into the stack overflow bug, but returns a None value for min_value even when I print out the min_value, it looks correct for every nodes.

Comment: You are welcome! As for your update: you are missing a `return` statement in your `minDiffInBST`, so it does not return any value, therefore resulting in `None`.